# Jenkins - Selecting tests

Tags: java, maven, junit, jenkins

I am currently working on a Maven Project, using JUnit for defining tests and Jenkins for CI and am looking into how I can group my tests.

Say I had a test class with 20 tests, but I don't want to run all 20 tests, I want to be able to configure which tests to run.  For Example, in another standalone project using TestNG and Selenium you can create a test method with the following annotation:

```
@Test (groups = { "AllTest" })
public void myTestMethod() 
{
  .. do something
  .. assert something
}
```

... and then I am able to call which group to run based on an XML configuration.

Is it possible to define such type of groupings using Jenkins?  I have researched into this and came across the plugin "Tests Selector Plugin" however can't understand how to get started once I've installed the plugin.  There is a [Wiki Page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Tests+Selector+Plugin) for it but I can't understand what to do after installing.

I have copy pasted the example property file, and didn't really understand what I needed to manipulate in it.  When building, I simply get that the property file cannot be found or Jenkins doesn't have permission; can't find a way around this either :(

Comment: For Tests Selector Plugin looks like you have to enter full path to the property file. Also you cannot use jenkins vars like $WORKSPACE. There is also https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selection+Tasks+Plugin which could be similarily useful. I also wish to configure which tests to run in jenkins gui driven by build scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible via maven + maven-surefire-plugin

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

You can run a single test, set of tests or tests by regexp.

Comment: Thanks @Stanjer!  I managed to run a single test once as per the link.  Oddly enough I didn't manage again though.  Trying other tests, and also the one that was previously successful but getting an error each time ... I keep getting MavenProject: No tests were executed!
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project MavenProject: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.).  Would you have any idea why?

Comment: Ok I think I'm doing something stupid. I have 10 tests, and renamed 3 of them to start with always_, I then committed and pushed to Git.  These 3 tests now continuously fail, the other 7 work fine though.  Can't really understand why :(

Comment: Do you mean executing them as single tests works and doesn't work if executing as a test suite?

Comment: Hi @Stanjer, actually had a spelling mistake :( Thanks for your input! All fine now :D